# What can I expect for battery life from my Nikon D5100?

Tags: battery, nikon-d5100, battery-drain

Recently I have purchased a Nikon d5100. In every shot I use live view (using the LCD), so basically live view is on when my camera is on. How many photos can I expect to snap in single full battery charge. The company claims 600+ snaps on single full battery charge, but I can only be able to get 125-140 photos  (including some slow shutter  photo at night with minimum  30 seconds of shutter speed).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must absolutely use the viewfinder but what I've also found useful is to turn off the camera between shots because unlike the D90, the D5100 does not have an idle mode and it will keep adjusting aperture & shutter (if you use the automatic preset) speed which also drains the battery a lot.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

From the [D5100's manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf) (page 81), the 600+ images is by the CIPA standard, and *does not* include live view — just 4 seconds of review for each image. It's not surprising at all that real-life usage is much less, particularly if you are using live view constantly.

Sadly, I think your options are:

1. Change your habits, or
2. Pick up some spare batteries.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question. About 125-140 sounds right. The live view is your biggest drain, so the longer it's on between shots, the less shots you'll get.

I don't use Live View, and have Image Review turned off, and I always carry a spare battery.  I shoot all day and often have to change batteries, but never use up the second.  Matt is right, if you want more battery life you may want to adjust your technique accordingly.  Once you get used to the viewfinder you'll rarely find a need for Live View.

Answer (score 0):

I don't continuously use live view, have photo review off, and can get way 1000+ shots out of one battery, even with leaving the camera on.